# Normalizing Video Volume using avconv

Tags: video-conversion, avconv

I have a collection of videos, in the `.mkv` and `.mp4` (AAC+H.264) formats. The `.mkv` files are ok, but all the `.mp4` files have such a low volume that I can hardly hear it on my phone, even when volume is maxed.

I convert them using `avconv` so they're smaller for my phone. It works fine, but I have not yet found out how I can normalize the volume on all the `.mp4` files so they match the `.mkv` files.

Just raising the volume alone would be a great achievement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just been searching for a similar problem and used [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg) from SuperUser

Basically, just extract the audio from the file as wav, run normalize-audio on it and then re-encode it as aac and remux.

I just wrote this quick script to do it:

```
VIDEO_FILE=$1
VIDEO_FILE_FIXED=${VIDEO_FILE%.*}-fixed.${VIDEO_FILE##*.}
avconv -i $VIDEO_FILE -c:a pcm_s16le -vn audio.wav
normalize-audio audio.wav
avconv -i $VIDEO_FILE -i audio.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a libvo_aacenc \
   $VIDEO_FILE_FIXED
```

Put it in a file like `normalize.sh`, then run `bash normalize.sh file_to_convert.mp4`.  You'll get a file out `file_to_convert-fixed.mp4`.

You might want to tweak the `normalize-audio` command to just raise the volume by some dB with the `-g` siwtch, or use another command entirely.  I saw **aacgain** and **wavegain** mentioned elsewhere.  `normalize-audio` is in the package **normalize-audio**, funnily enough.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Based on this website https://wiki.libav.org/Snippets/avconv, I changed the last line to this: avconv -i $VIDEO_FILE -i audio.wav -c copy $VIDEO_FILE_FIXED

Comment: @chrisdembia it would be helpful to know why did you do this?

Comment: I don't completely remember; this is my guess: "-c copy" uses the same audio and video encoders from the input, and those were the encoders I wanted to use.

Comment: @chrisdembia are you sure it worked. The link you gave appears to assume the video file being taking in as input does not have an audio stream on it.

Comment: I think I didn't have audio in my input. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

In [OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) you can increase the volume of a video by 150%.